# SICP Streams (Scheme) - CDR into the implicit stream of ones

Tags: stream, scheme, read-eval-print-loop, sicp, mit-scheme

```lisp
(define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))
(stream-cdr ones)
```

returns an infinite sequence of evaluated 1s - i.e. I get
`;Value: #0={1 1 1 1 1 1 1`  and so on... - not the symbolic `{1 1 ...}` I would expect ...

On the other end if I define `ints` and `cdr` into it,

```lisp
(define ints (cons-stream 1 (stream-map + ones ints)))
(stream-cdr ints)
```

I obtain the expected `{1 2 ...}`

Can anyone explain me why? I expect the `stream-map` definition to be not too far from

```lisp
(define (mystream-map proc . argstreams) 
    (if (stream-null? (car argstreams))
            the-empty-stream
        (cons-stream
            (apply proc (map stream-car argstreams)) 
            (apply mystream-map (cons proc (map stream-cdr argstreams))))))
```

which I defined in ex 3.50 and returns the same result ... but this seems to (via `(map stream-cdr argstreams)`) `stream-cdr` into ones, which I would expect to result in the infinite sequence I get above!

Even though, if I understand correctly, due to `cons-stream` being a macro the second part inside the `stream-map` will only be lazily evaluated, at some point while I `cdr` into the `ints` stream I would expect to have to `cdr` into `ones` as well.. which instead doesn't seem to be happening! :/
Any help in understanding this would be very much appreciated!

(I also didn't override any scheme symbol and I'm running everything in MIT Scheme - Release 11.2 on OS X.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> (define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))
> (stream-cdr ones)
> ```
>
> returns an infinite sequence of evaluated `ones`.

No it does not. `(stream-cdr ones) = (stream-cdr (cons-stream 1 ones)) = ones`. It is just one `ones`, not the sequence of `ones`.

And what is `ones`?

Its `stream-car` is `1`, and its `stream-cdr` is `ones`.

Whose `stream-car` is `1`, and `stream-cdr` is `ones` again.

And so if you `(stream-take n ones)` (with an obvious implementation of `stream-take`) you will receive an `n`-long list of `1`s, whatever the (non-negative) `n` is.

In other words, repeated `cdr`ing into `ones` produces an unbounded sequence of `1`s. Or symbolically, `{1 1 1 ...}` indeed.

---

After your edit it becomes clear the question is about REPL behavior. What you're seeing most probably has to do with the difference between sharing and recalculation, just like in `letrec` with the true reuse (achieved through self-referring binding) vs. the **`Y`** combinator with the recalculation (`(Y g) == g (Y g)`).

You probably can see the behavior you're expecting, with the re-calculating definition `(define (onesF) (cons-stream 1 (onesF)))`.

I only have Racket, where

```
(define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))
(define (onesF) (cons-stream 1 (onesF)))
(define ints (cons-stream 1 (stream-map + ones ints)))

(stream-cdr ones)
(stream-cdr (onesF))
(stream-cdr ints)
```

prints

```
(mcons 1 #<promise>)
(mcons 1 #<promise>)
(mcons 2 #<promise>)
```

Furthermore, having defined

```
(define (take n s)
  (if (<= n 1)
      (if (= n 1)    ; prevent an excessive `force`
          (list (stream-car s))
          '())
      (cons (stream-car s)
            (take (- n 1)
                  (stream-cdr s)))))
```

we get

```
> (display (take 5 ones))
(1 1 1 1 1)
> (display (take 5 (onesF)))
(1 1 1 1 1)
> (display (take 5 ints))
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: My bad, I wrote the part you’re quoting in a confusing way, I'll edit that, I meant an infinite sequence of evaluated 1s, i.e.

`=> (stream-cdr ones)`

`;Value: #0={1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

and it just doesn't stop :p

Conceptually I'm fine with this stream, and your answer is totally correct, I just don't understand how it's working since I get this output from the REPL ...

Comment: oh, that's quite a different question indeed. it is not about Scheme semantics (what I was answering) but rather about specific REPL's behavior. IOW it doesn't matter what REPL is printing. :) as to why, I can guess it has to do with the _sharing vs copying_ thing. I.e. is it (in pseudocode) like ``ones = cons(1, ones)`` or ``ones() = cons(1, ones())`` -- does it compute the same tail anew or does it refer to _the same tail_ (even in the `eq?` sense).

Comment: or in Scheme (d'oh) it's `(define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))` vs. `(define (ones) (cons-stream 1 (ones)))`. Could you try the last one and tell me what's happening then, in your REPL? :)

Comment: Ah! Indeed! `1 ]=> (stream-cdr (onesF)) ;Value: {1 ...}`

So just a matter of how the REPL display things? For some reason a "too simple" implicit stream definition confuses it ... Thanks!